# Why can't my Azure ACI container reach the internet?

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-container-instances

Is it normal that a container running on Azure ACI is not able to reach the internet?

I need my ACI container to send data to a webhook on the internet, but Azure seems to block outbound traffic from any ACI instance.
If so, how can i resolve/workaround this issue?

Apart from the image that i am using (I guess not revelant), there is not too much configuration I added. I only set the port to 2000 instead of 80 as the container will need to listen only on this port ( i assume it is inbound only) Anyway config shows:

```
 OS type: Linux IP address: - SKU: Standard FQDN: - DNS name label scope reuse: - DNS name label: - Ports: 2000 Restart policy: On failure Container count: 1 Key management: Microsoft-managed keys (MMK) Resource ID: ...
```

If i enter the console i get not answer from: / # ping 8.8.8.8 PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes

Comment: Outbound is open by default, can you share more configuration from your environment?

Comment: please see details above

Answer (score 0):

As per this [microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mast/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity), it seems ICMP traffic restriction has been applied and
the **ping** command in ACI only works within a Vnet (by Default). It is not working outside of the vnet. You can use other commands such as `telnet` or `nslookup` to check the internet access of the container.

`telnet 8.8.8.8 443`

[image]

```
nslookup www.google.com
```

[image]

If the `nslookup` or `telnet` command is not executing, use the below commands to install the module.

for Debian/Ubuntu

```
apt update
apt install dnsutils
apt install telnet
```

for RHEL/fedora

```
dnf update
dnf install bind-utils
dnf install telnet
```